Removing timestamp from label in Apex Graph
Below is the code I'm trying to run.  I made the repo_date format CHAR so that I can take the timestamp out of the label.  However, when I do that, the sorting gets messed up.  I'm sorting by the actual repo date as below but still the sorting is wrong.
I run this:
select null link,
to_char(repo_month, 'mm/yyyy') label,
count(distinct(account_number)) voluntary
from repo_tracking_for_mm_mv
where surrender_status is not null
and original_amount > 0
and surrender_status = 'INVOLUNTRY'
group by repo_month
order by repo_month

And get this:
Example Graph:

I am just trying to get the timestamp out of the repo_month label.  I did that by using TO_CHAR.  But the sorting is wrong even though I put "order by repo_month"

You might change that example to not reflect that this is about repoing cars because I suspect some people might not help you.
